# How to detect if user tap on sym or emoji button in android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, keycode

i have been using dispatchKeyEvent to get the keycode of android keyboard but the problem is when i tap on Sym or Emoji button nothing happen, no keycode shows. this is the code i use to get the keycode:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "key pressed : "+ String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PICTSYMBOLS for emoji.

```
/*
     * Respond to soft keyboard events, look for the DONE press on the password field.
     */
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PICTSYMBOLS))
        {
            // Done pressed!  Do something here.
        }
        // Returning false allows other listeners to react to the press.
        return false;
    }
```